# Foundation watch throws gulp errors

Tags: gulp, zurb-foundation-6

I messed up my local project with Foundation 6 but I had everything on a remote web server so I downloaded my project to a local folder. When I tried to run `foundation watch` I got errors

```
sh: /myfolder/node_modules/.bin/gulp: Permission denied
Error: foundation-sites-template@1.0.0 start: `gulp`
Exit status 126
    at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/foundation-cli/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:217:16)
    at emitTwo (events.js:100:13)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/foundation-cli/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:24:14)
    at emitTwo (events.js:100:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:850:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:5)
```

Is that fixable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whatever means of copying you used probably messed up the executable bit of `/myfolder/node_modules/.bin/gulp`. Type the following in a terminal:

```
chmod a+x /myfolder/node_modules/.bin/gulp
```

There might be other files with permission issues, so it's probably best to just delete the the whole `node_modules` folder and `npm install` from scratch.

Comment: I saw this answer after I deleted everything and started from scratch :(

Comment: Just to let you know - this works. I had to delete node modules and run npm install. After that foundation watch continued to do it's job. Thanks